# python: use scipy savemat causes PermissionError

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, mat

I tried to save the processed data into a .mat file in Windows but caused PermissionError. The same code works fine on Mac OX.

Here's the code

```
import scipy as scio
import os
dataNew='M:\\fwdh\members\\gundrum\\FuerPrecess\\Auswertung\\D881_channel_1.mat'
scio.savemat(dataNew,{'channel_1':channel_1})
```

And the error was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gao98\Desktop\final.py", line 196, in <module>
scio.savemat(dataNew,{'channel_1':channel_1})
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 193, in savemat
file_stream = open(file_name, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'M:\\fwdh\\members\\gundrum\\FuerPrecess\\Auswertung\\D881_channel_1.mat'
```

Anyone who can please tell me where goes wrong? thanks

Comment: Seems like the account/process trying to save the file doesn't have access to the directory specified.

Comment: Are you able to, say, paste files into that directory?  Or use Notepad to save a txt file in there?

Comment: I run the code in python 3.6 Shell by the way

Comment: @YingqiangGao, make sure that this file is NOT opened by another program

Comment: Yeah it's not opened by another program

Comment: Problems solved. I found that I don't have the rights to write in this folder. Thanks guys :)